# Checking 2 arrays to see if they have the same values?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to compare two arrays to see if they have the same values.

If I have a array called

```
public static float data[][]
```

which holds Y coordinates of a terrain, how can I check that array with another

```
public static int coords[][]
```

without iterating through all the coordinates?

Both arrays have over 1000 values in them. Iterating through them is not an option, since I must iterate through them over four times per second.

I am doing this to attempt to find if two objects are colliding. I have attempted using libraries for this, however I cannot find per-coordinate collision detection as specific as I need it.

Edit: Why I am unable to just iterate through this small amount of vertices is this.
The problem is, this is a MultiPlayer game,and I would have to iterate through all 1000 coordinates for every player. Meaning that just 10 players online is 10,000 100 online is 100,000. You can see how easily that would lag or at least take up a large percentage of the CPU.

Input of coordinates into the "Data" variable:

```
try {
        // Load the heightmap-image from its resource file

        BufferedImage heightmapImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "res/images/heightmap.bmp"));
        //width = heightmapImage.getWidth();
        //height = heightmapImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage heightmapColour = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "res/images/colours.bmp"));
        // Initialise the data array, which holds the heights of the
        // heightmap-vertices, with the correct dimensions
        data = new float[heightmapImage.getWidth()][heightmapImage
                .getHeight()];
        // collide = new int[heightmapImage.getWidth()][50][heightmapImage.getHeight()];
        red = new float[heightmapColour.getWidth()][heightmapColour
                .getHeight()];
        blue = new float[heightmapColour.getWidth()][heightmapColour
                .getHeight()];
        green = new float[heightmapColour.getWidth()][heightmapColour
                .getHeight()];
        // Lazily initialise the convenience class for extracting the
        // separate red, green, blue, or alpha channels
        // an int in the default RGB color model and default sRGB
        // colourspace.
        Color colour;
        Color colours;
        // Iterate over the pixels in the image on the x-axis
        for (int z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
            // Iterate over the pixels in the image on the y-axis
            for (int x = 0; x < data[z].length; x++) {
                colour = new Color(heightmapImage.getRGB(z, x));

                data[z][x] = setHeight;

            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

And how coordinates are put into the "coords" variable (Oh wait, it was called "Ship", not coords. I forgot that):

```
try{
        File f = new File("res/images/coords.txt");
        String coords = readTextFile(f.getAbsolutePath());

        for (int i = 0; i < coords.length();){
            int i1 = i;
            for (; i1 < coords.length(); i1++){
                if (String.valueOf(coords.charAt(i1)).contains(",")){
                    break;
                }
            }
            String x = coords.substring(i, i1).replace(",", "");
            i = i1;
            i1 = i + 1;
            for (; i1 < coords.length(); i1++){
                if (String.valueOf(coords.charAt(i1)).contains(",")){
                    break;
                }
            }
            String y = coords.substring(i, i1).replace(",", "");;
            i = i1;
            i1 = i + 1;
            for (; i1 < coords.length(); i1++){
                if (String.valueOf(coords.charAt(i1)).contains(",")){
                    break;
                }
            }
            String z = coords.substring(i, i1).replace(",", "");;
            i = i1 + 1;
                //buildx.append(String.valueOf(coords.charAt(i)));
                ////System.out.println(x);
                ////System.out.println(y);
                ////System.out.println(z);
                //x = String.valueOf((int)Double.parseDouble(x));
                //y = String.valueOf((int)Double.parseDouble(y));
                //z = String.valueOf((int)Double.parseDouble(z));
            double sx = Double.valueOf(x);
            double sy =  Double.valueOf(y);
            double sz = Double.valueOf(z);
            javax.vecmath.Vector3f cor = new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(x), Float.parseFloat(y), Float.parseFloat(z));
            //if (!arr.contains(cor)){
            if (cor.y > 0)
                arr.add(new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(cor));


            if (!ship.contains(new Vector3f((int) sx, (int) sy, (int) sz)))
                ship.add(new Vector3f((int) sx, (int) sy, (int) sz));
```

//                  arr.add(new javax.vecmath.Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(x), Float.parseFloat(y), Float.parseFloat(z)));
                }
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried (and profiled) anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "having the same values"? Same values in order? Same values in random order?

Comment: You know, 1000 values is really small. You can iterate over that a few hundred thousand times a second on a laptop.

Comment: Please put some sample data for data[][] and coords[][]

Comment: @RakeshSoni I updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this but only applicable for same data type.

```
 Arrays.deepEquals(data, coords);
```

For single dimension Array you can use this

```
 Arrays.equals(array1, array1);
```

Comment: @Keppil agree on your question its only applicable for compare two same datatype arrays.

Comment: Does that check if they are the same or just have intersecting coordinates? They are never going to be the same, however they may have coordinates that are the same.
Anyway I will try what you have suggested. Thanks!

Comment: So then this doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @Joehot "intersecting coordinates" doesn't mean anything in itself. Also, don't be fooled by the fact that the comparison is hidden in a function, ie "Arrays.equals(...)". It will still just loop through all elements all the same.

Comment: From the OP : **Iterating through them is not an option**... This is not the answer (there is none, btw)

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.deepEquals(a, b);
```

**Try this but this will work only if the elements are in order.**

Answer (score 0):

No way around it, I'm afraid. Comparing data sets to see if they are identical demands looking at all elements, by definition. On a side note, comparing 1000 values is nothing even on relatively old hardware. You can do it thousands of time per second.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer.

The problem is, this is a MultiPlayer game,and I would have to iterate through all 1000 coordinates for every player.
Meaning that just 10 players online is 10,000
100 online is 100,000.
Can you see how this is just impossible for a computer to do?

Anyway, Shame there is no way around it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Joehot200 It may be possible to optimize your problem (very probably is) by taking advantage of the higher level structure of your data, but there is not enough information for someone to help you with that here. The only thing I could say here is that the comparison of two arrays for equality can stop right away when a difference is found. If the third elements differ for example, you will only make 3 comparisons instead of 1000. hope this helps.